# Inserting into to listview from another thread

Tags: c#, listview, invoke

I'm trying to insert an email form another thread to the Form1 listview, but somehow it doesn't work. Here's my code:

```
    private delegate void InsertIntoListDelegate(string email);
    private void InsertIntoList(string email)
    {
        if (f1.listView1.InvokeRequired)
        {
            f1.listView1.Invoke(new InsertIntoListDelegate(InsertIntoList), email);
        }
        else
        {
            f1.listView1.Items.Add(email);
            f1.listView1.Refresh();
        }
    }
```

If you can help me then thank you.

Comment: `it doesn't work` What doesn't work? What error do you get?

Comment: No errors, it just doesn't add anything into Listview.

Comment: if (!f1.InvokeRequired) throw new Exception("Invalid form object");

Comment: @Jason I tested your code and it works. `new Thread(()=>{InsertIntoList("test");}).Start();`

Comment: @Jason just to point out, L.B's is showing his test, not a solution

Comment: @Jason Is it possible that your listView1.View==`Details`? If yes try to set to `List`

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
    private delegate void InsertIntoListDelegate(string email);
    public void InsertIntoList(string email)
    {
        if(InvokeRequired)
        {
            Invoke(new InsertIntoListDelegate(InsertIntoList), email);
        }
        else
        {
            f1.listView1.Items.Add(email);
            f1.listView1.Refresh();
        }
    }
```

**InsertIntoList** is a member of the enclosing control so should be invoked on that control not the list view.

Try this very simple test which works for me:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private delegate void InsertIntoListDelegate(string email);

    public void InsertIntoList(string email)
    {
        if(InvokeRequired)
        {
            Invoke(new InsertIntoListDelegate(InsertIntoList), email);
        }
        else
        {
            listView1.Items.Add(email);
        }
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        Task.Factory.StartNew(() => InsertIntoList("test"));
    }
}
```

Comment: Hey Phil, somehow it doesn't work. Or if it works, then it doesn't refresh the Listview because I don't see anything inside it :(

Comment: Hm, I don't know why it didn't work, but I changed listview to richtextbox and it works perfectly well.